# Why does version->parse fail to work without preceding print?

Tags: perl, version

I have to admit, this one has me foxed.

Consider this code:

```
use version;
use Data::Dumper;
my $codeLevel = q{6.1.0.7 (build 25.3.1103030000)};
print STDERR qq{$codeLevel\n};
my $vrmf;
if($codeLevel =~ /^\s*([0-9.]*) \(build.*\)/) { 
    print STDERR "$1\n";
    $vrmf = version->parse($1);
}

print STDERR Dumper($vrmf);
```

The output, as expected, is:

```
6.1.0.7 (build 25.3.1103030000)
6.1.0.7
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'original' => '6.1.0.7',
                 'qv' => 1,
                 'version' => [
                                6,
                                1,
                                0,
                                7
                              ]
               }, 'version' );
```

However, remove the second print:

```
use version;
use Data::Dumper;
my $codeLevel = q{6.1.0.7 (build 25.3.1103030000)};
print STDERR qq{$codeLevel\n};
my $vrmf;
if($codeLevel =~ /^\s*([0-9.]*) \(build.*\)/) {
    $vrmf = version->parse($1);
}
print STDERR Dumper($vrmf);
```

The output becomes:

```
6.1.0.7 (build 25.3.1103030000)
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'original' => '0',
                 'version' => [
                                0
                              ]
               }, 'version' );
```

I can't find any documentation that says that `print` can affect variables passed to it, or that it affects the regex matching variables.

Can someone explain to me what is happening here, please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Scalar values in Perl can be a number and a string *at the same time*. An SV object (SV = Scalar Value) has slots for integer, float, and string values and flags identifying which of those values are valid at any point in time. When you use a value as a string perl calculates the string value and sets a flag identifying it as valid. (Other operations, like adding 1 would invalidate the string value.) When you print something you're (unsurprisingly) using it as a string. You can see this using Devel::Peek.

```
use Devel::Peek;

my $s = '6.1.0.7 (build 25.3.1103030000)';
if ($s =~ /^\s*([0-9.]*) \(build.*\)/) { 
    Dump($1);
    printf STDERR "\$1 = $1\n";
    Dump($1);
}
```

The result is

```
SV = PVMG(0x1434ca4) at 0x144d83c
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (GMG,SMG)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0
  MAGIC = 0x146c324
    MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_sv
    MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_sv(\0)
    MG_OBJ = 0x144d82c
    MG_LEN = 1
    MG_PTR = 0x14631c4 "1"
$1 = 6.1.0.7
SV = PVMG(0x1434ca4) at 0x144d83c
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (GMG,SMG,pPOK)
  IV = 0
  NV = 0
  PV = 0x1487a1c "6.1.0.7"\0
  CUR = 7
  LEN = 8
  MAGIC = 0x146c324
    MG_VIRTUAL = &PL_vtbl_sv
    MG_TYPE = PERL_MAGIC_sv(\0)
    MG_OBJ = 0x144d82c
    MG_LEN = 1
    MG_PTR = 0x14631c4 "1"
```

Note that in the second dump output the PV slot (string value) has been populated and the pPOK flag has been added under FLAGS.

So, yes, `print` has side-effects of a sort although under normal circumstances you should never notice. `version->parse()` appears to expect a string argument but isn't triggering string semantics. Given that `version` prefers to use an XS implementation, it's probably a bug there rather than in perl. Note that making a copy of the capture data causes the problem to disappear:

```
use Data::Dump qw'pp';

my $s = '6.1.0.7 (build 25.3.1103030000)';
if ($s =~ /^\s*([0-9.]*) \(build.*\)/) { 
    my $x = $1;
    pp(version->parse($x));
}
```

Result:

```
bless({ original => "6.1.0.7", qv => 1, version => [6, 1, 0, 7] }, "version")
```

Answer (score 4):

Looks like a bug in version::parse, that it isn't properly triggering get magic on the incoming parameter.

Looking at the code shows the same problem in the CPAN and core "versions"; it's checking SvOK long before handling get magic.  Unfortunately, this will involve a fix both in the module code and the perl core.

Comment: version has so many of these odd issues reaching into user's programs that I try to never use it.

Answer (score 3):

This reproduces with Perl 5.14.1 on MacOS X 10.6.8, using the XS implementation of 'version' 0.91 (that's version version 0.91)...

However, it is a bug in the `version::vxs` (XS implementation), not the `version::vpp` (pure Perl) implementation.

```
use version::vxs;
use Data::Dumper;
my $codeLevel = q{6.1.0.7 (build 25.3.1103030000)};
print STDERR qq{$codeLevel\n};
my $vrmf;
if($codeLevel =~ /^\s*([0-9.]*) \(build.*\)/) { 
    $vrmf = version::vxs->parse($1);
}

print STDERR Dumper($vrmf);
```

That fails as you showed.  When I compiled the pure Perl version (`perl Makefile.PL --perl_only`, as mentioned in the README file), and tested it, it worked correctly:

```
$ perl -Iblib/lib x4.pl
6.1.0.7 (build 25.3.1103030000)
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'original' => '6.1.0.7',
                 'qv' => 1,
                 'version' => [
                                6,
                                1,
                                0,
                                7
                              ]
               }, 'version::vpp' );

$ cat x4.pl
use version::vpp;
use Data::Dumper;
my $codeLevel = q{6.1.0.7 (build 25.3.1103030000)};
print STDERR qq{$codeLevel\n};
my $vrmf;
if($codeLevel =~ /^\s*([0-9.]*) \(build.*\)/) { 
    $vrmf = version::vpp->parse($1);
}

print STDERR Dumper($vrmf);
$
```

I think you could sensibly [report this on CPAN RT](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Create.html?Queue=version) (the author is JPEACOCK).  As a workaround, manually install the pure Perl version and remove the XS version (because the code looks for the XS code first - see [`version-0.91/lib/version.pm`](http://cpan.uwinnipeg.ca/htdocs/version/version.pm.html)).  If you're really brave, consider working out what the actual bug is.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it always the way; you ask a question and then find the answer!

This code:

```
use version;
use Data::Dumper;
my $codeLevel = q{6.1.0.7 (build 25.3.1103030000)};
print STDERR qq{$codeLevel\n};
my $vrmf;
if($codeLevel =~ /^\s*([0-9.]*) \(build.*\)/) {
    $vrmf = version->parse("$1");
}
print STDERR Dumper($vrmf);
```

Works correctly. Note that $1 has been stringified here.

Still, that leaves an interesting observation: that printing a variable seems to permanently stringify it!

Comment: Yes, `print` needs a string version to print it.  Using a variable in string context causes `perl` to cache the string.  You may find `Devel::Peek` helpful in understanding what is going on under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the particular magic behind version numbers, but with `overload` you can give practically any side-effect you want to stringification.

```
package My::Class;
use overload
    '""' => \&arbitrary_function;

...

$obj = My::Class->new();
print $obj;                 # invokes &arbitrary_function
```

Comment: Yikes... that seems like a horrible way to introduce subtle bugs. Still... pretty cool too :)